# How to write SQL query to rank each unique users's actions by time stamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best way to rank actions for each user by time stamp in SQL (Postgres)?

So essentially, I have this kind of table.

```
Time Stamp | UserId | Action |

1. 05-19-2019 01:01 , cooldude, 102
2. 05-19-2019 07:06 , cooldude, 201
3. 05-19-2019 05:04 , cooldude, 241
4. 05-19-2019 01:00 , secondman, 199
```

And I want it create a rank for the order of actions by a user on a given day like:

```
Time Stamp | UserId | Action | Rank

1. 05-19-2019 01:01 , cooldude, 102, 1
2. 05-19-2019 07:06 , cooldude, 201, 3
3. 05-19-2019 05:04 , cooldude, 241, 2
4. 05-19-2019 01:00 , secondman, 199, 1
```

This is my first time on here - so please excuse the terrible formatting. I would really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: Your sample data only includes a single date, but you want a rank "on a given day". Does that mean that you want the rank to start from `1` on each date for each user, i.e. if there were rows for `05-20-2019` would the rank values continue to count up or reset to `1`?

Comment: It is actually pleasant to see someone taking concern over "terrible formatting" - which yours is **definitely not**. But you may want to look into a table generator such as [Ascii Table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) or [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/). Copy the results into you question surrounding them with ``` characters (that's chr(96), x'60' ),

Comment: @HABO Well I guess I wasn't very clear on that. I ended up partitioning by the "m/d/yyyy" and the persona id since I wanted the actions rate for each user on each day separately.

Comment: @Belayer thank you for the links! Will definitely use it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by userid order by timestamp) as ranking
from t;
```

`row_number()` returns an enumeration, with no duplicates.  `rank()` will returns duplicates when the values are tied.